# EF Core 3.1 throws an exception for Contains

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-3.0

I recently updated the project code into .NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 3.1, now most of my linq queries brake, EX.

```
public override ICollection<ContactDetailModel> GetAll(ICollection<int> ids)
{
            return _context
                .Set<TEntity>()
                .IgnoreDeletedEntities()                
                .Where(x => ids.Distinct().Contains(x.ContactId))                
                .Select(EntityToDTOMapper)
                .ToList();
}
```

This code throws an error where I use Contains, I saw in some other posts this issues has been fixed as a bug, but yet it fails.

Error I get is "could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()."

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The LINQ expression 'DbSet<SupplierContactDetails>
    .Where(s => !(s.DeletedOn.HasValue) && !(s.DeletedBy.HasValue))
    .Where(s => __Distinct_0
        .Contains(s.ContactId))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass8_0& )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at BlueTag.DAL.Repositories.ContactRepository`1.GetAll(ICollection`1 ids) in D:\Projects\BlueTag Version 2\.net-core-server\DAL\Repositories\ContactRepository.cs:line 95
   at BlueTag.DAL.Repositories.SupplierRepository.ToDomain(IEnumerable`1 supplier) in D:\Projects\BlueTag Version 2\.net-core-server\DAL\Repositories\SupplierRepository.cs:line 216
   at BlueTag.DAL.Repositories.SupplierRepository.GetFilteredSuppliers(RequestPagingOptionsModel`1 options) in D:\Projects\BlueTag Version 2\.net-core-server\DAL\Repositories\SupplierRepository.cs:line 129
   at BlueTag.Supplier.Services.SupplierService.GetFilteredSupplierDetails(RequestPagingOptionsModel`1 options) in D:\Projects\BlueTag Version 2\.net-core-server\Supplier\Serrvices\SupplierService.cs:line 49
   at BlueTag.Supplier.Controllers.SupplierController.GetFilteredSuppliers(RequestPagingOptionsModel`1 options) in D:\Projects\BlueTag Version 2\.net-core-server\Supplier\Controllers\SupplierController.cs:line 54
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Comment: There are still many bugs in EF Core query translation. But are you sure the problem is the above `Where` condition? Because it works for me (EF Core 3.1.1 and also 3.1.2). Can you post the exception stack trace and/or the full error message.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The LINQ expression 'DbSet<SupplierContactDetails>
    .Where(s => !(s.DeletedOn.HasValue) && !(s.DeletedBy.HasValue))
    .Where(s => __Distinct_0
        .Contains(s.ContactId))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: I removed part by part of the linq query, it fails at the where clause

Comment: How about commenting out `.IgnoreDeletedEntities()`?

Comment: still the same, as I told before it fails when where clause is added.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, Not yet. do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework cannot translate every query, and as such it sometimes has to load all the data and perform the LINQ expression in-memory, this is called Client Side Evaluation and is not desired, as it is more resource intensive and takes longer. For your specific problem, there are 2 solutions, both of which are outlined in the error message.

1) Rewrite your LINQ queries to include explicit calls to client side evaluation versus implicit calls

or

2) Rewrite your LINQ queries to not need client side evaluation

You could do number 1 like so:

```cs
public override ICollection<ContactDetailModel> GetAll(ICollection<int> ids)
{
    return _context
        .Set<TEntity>()
        .IgnoreDeletedEntities()
        .ToList()                
        .Where(x => ids.Distinct().Contains(x.ContactId))                
        .Select(EntityToDTOMapper)
        .ToList();
}
```

Notice the explicit call to `ToList` after `IgnoreDeletedEntities`, this needs to be done to explicitly switch to client side evaluation so your `Where` statement will properly execute and not throw any errors. This is because `x => ids.Distinct().Contains(x.ContactId)` cannot be translated to SQL (or whatever) by your version of EF.

Number 2 could be solved like so:

```cs
public override ICollection<ContactDetailModel> GetAll(ICollection<int> ids)
{
    ids = ids.Distinct();
    return _context
        .Set<TEntity>()
        .IgnoreDeletedEntities()
        .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ContactId))
        .Select(EntityToDTOMapper)
        .ToList();
}
```

Notice how I moved the use of `ids.Distinct()` from the `Where` to the top, as that was the part EF couldn't translate

Comment: Thank you for the fast Reply, I clearly understand client evaluation and server evaluation, part what I cant understand is Contains/ Distinct was never evaluated at client side. so why it fails now in .net core 3.x?. I have tried Number 2 way but it still fails. even added AsEnumerable before and After Where Clause, yet it fails. Number 1 solution wont be efficient fix as it loads all into memory.

Comment: @Shivanka the reason for why is the first breaking change on [breaking changes in Entity Framework Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) ([this one here to be specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client))

Comment: Moving the call to `Distinct()` outside the `Where()` does nothing in itself; it creates an `IEnumerable<int>` that needs to be evaluated, and still cannot be converted to SQL. It will also need `ToArray()` or `ToList()` to create a structure that EF can work with.

Comment: Would appreciate if someone can suggest a way to refactor the linq query to be evaluated in server side

Comment: Yes, and no luck

Comment: @Shivanka does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58690829/9363973) solve it?

Comment: hi, can you answer this question? thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802339/c-net-core-3-1-contains-linq-causes-client-side-exception-error