# LINQ Left Outer Join Multiple Tables with Group Count and Row Concatenation

Tags: linq, group-by, left-join, multi-table

Can someone help with below please? I simplified the table/column names, etc. I search everywhere but the answers I get are incomplete solutions for the results I want to achieve below.  New to LINQ so please be kind. :-)

**TABLES**

- **Parent** (ParentId, ParentName, ParentOccupation)
- **Child** (ChildId, ChildName, OtherField, ParentId)
- **GrandChild** (GrandChildId, GrandChildName, OtherField, ChildId)

**Parent**

```
+----------+------------+------------------+
| ParentId | ParentName | ParentOccupation |
+----------+------------+------------------+
| 1        | Mary       | Teacher          |
| 2        | Anne       | Doctor           |
| 3        | Michael    | Farmer           |
| 4        | Elizabeth  | Police           |
| 5        | Andrew     | Fireman          |
+----------+------------+------------------+
```

**Child**

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| ChildId | ChildName | OtherField  | ParentId |
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| 1       | Ashley    | [SomeValue] | 1        |
| 2       | Brooke    | [SomeValue] | 1        |
| 3       | Ashton    | [SomeValue] | 3        |
| 4       | Emma      | [SomeValue] | 4        |
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

**GrandChild**

```
+--------------+----------------+-------------+---------+
| GrandChildId | GrandChildName | OtherField  | ChildId |
+--------------+----------------+-------------+---------+
| 1            | Andrew         | [SomeValue] | 1       |
| 2            | Isabelle       | [SomeValue] | 2       |
| 3            | Lucas          | [SomeValue] | 2       |
| 4            | Matthew        | [SomeValue] | 4       |
+--------------+----------------+-------------+---------+
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
+----------+------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| ParentId | ParentName | ParentOccupation | NumberOfGrandChildren | NamesOfGrandChildren    |
+----------+------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| 1        | Mary       | Teacher          | 3                     | Andrew, Isabelle, Lucas |
| 2        | Anne       | Doctor           | 0                     |                         |   
| 3        | Michael    | Farmer           | 0                     |                         |
| 4        | Elizabeth  | Police           | 1                     | Matthew                 |
| 5        | Andrew     | Fireman          | 0                     |                         | 
+----------+------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
```

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR**

**LEFT OUTER JOINS** - getting all the columns but no aggregates

```
var result1 = (from p in Parent
               join c in Child on p.ParentId equals c.ParentId into pcj
               from pc in pcj.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join g in GrandChild on pc.ChildId equals g.ChildId into cgj
               from cg in cgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where [some criteria]
               select new 
               {
                  ParentId = p.ParentId,
                  ParentName = p.ParentName,
                  ChildId = pc.ChildId,
                  ChildName = pc.ChildName,
                  GrandChildId = cg.GrandChildId,
                  GrandChildName = cg.GrandChildName   
               });
```

**COUNTS** - contain the aggregate but not all parent columns are there.  Also returns 1 in the count, instead of 0.

```
var result2 = (from p in Parent
               join c in Child on p.ParentId equals c.ParentId into pcj
               from pc in pcj.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join g in GrandChild on pc.ChildId equals g.ChildId into cgj
               from cg in cgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where [some criteria]
               group new { p } by new { p.ParentId } into r
               select new 
               {
                  ParentId = r.Key.Id,
                  NumberOfGrandChildren = r.Count()
               });
```

**CONCATENATE COMMA SEPARATED ROW VALUES** (for names of grandchildren) - have not attempted yet until I solve the count above, but open for solutions please.

How can I combine and achieve the results above?  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using EF, and you have navigation properties set up, then your query would look like this:

```
var result = context.Parents
  .Select(p => new {
    p.ParentId,
    p.ParentName,
    p.ParentOccupation,
    NumberOfGrandChildren = p.Children
       .SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren)
       .Count(),
    NamesOfGrandChildren = string.Join(", ", p.Children
      .SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren)
      .Select(g => g.GrandChildName))
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Robert. Unfortunately, I am getting this error: "SqlException: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.".

Comment: Interesting.  Have you tried the commented out version? That is a single aggregate.

Comment: As I said in my edited answer, Robert McKee's answer is more relevant. I also have no error running both versions of the query in Linqpad using EFCore and Sqlite.

Comment: @RobertMcKee. For some reason, I was getting an error in both last night.  But I tried it again with the commented part and it worked!  As Laurent has also indicated, I'll tag yours as the answer.  Thank you again!

Comment: Editted answer to remove the first method, and uncomment the second method so that it reflects what the OP found to work for him.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

New comments posted by the author of the question show that the Linq query involves EF Core. My original answer assumed it was a local query (Linq to Object). In fact, it rather seems to be an interpreted query (Linq to Entities).

See [linq to entities vs linq to objects - are they the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192040/linq-to-entities-vs-linq-to-objects-are-they-the-same) for explanations about the distinction between Linq to object and Linq to entities.

In that case, Robert McKee's answer is more to the point.

For curiosity's sake, Linqpad shows that this query:

```cs
Parents
    .Select(p => new
    {
        ParentId = p.Id,
        ParentName = p.Name,
        ParentOccupation = p.Occupation,
        GrandChildrenCount = p.Children
            .SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren)
            .Count(),
        GranchildrenNames = string.Join(", ", p.Children
            .SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren)
            .Select(gc => gc.Name))
    });
```

will be translated to the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT "p"."Id", "p"."Name", "p"."Occupation", (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM "Children" AS "c"
    INNER JOIN "GrandChildren" AS "g" ON "c"."Id" = "g"."ChildId"
    WHERE "p"."Id" = "c"."ParentId"), "t"."Name", "t"."Id", "t"."Id0"
FROM "Parents" AS "p"
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "g0"."Name", "c0"."Id", "g0"."Id" AS "Id0", "c0"."ParentId"
    FROM "Children" AS "c0"
    INNER JOIN "GrandChildren" AS "g0" ON "c0"."Id" = "g0"."ChildId"
) AS "t" ON "p"."Id" = "t"."ParentId"
ORDER BY "p"."Id", "t"."Id", "t"."Id0"
```

(Using Sqlite, and a custom EFCore context containing Entity Classes with navigation properties)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER - assuming Linq to object**

Here is a way you could construct your query.

```cs
var Result = Parents
    // Stage 1: for each parent, get its Chidren Ids
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Parent = p,
        ChildrenIds = Children
            .Where(c => c.ParentId == p.Id)
            .Select(c => c.Id)
            .ToList()
    })
    // Stage 2: for each parent, get its Grandchildren, by using the childrenIds list constructed before
    .Select(p => new
    {
        p.Parent,
        GrandChildren = Grandchildren
            .Where(gc => p.ChildrenIds.Contains(gc.ChildId))
            .ToList()
    })
    // Stage 3: for each parent, count the grandchildren, and get their names
    .Select(p => new
    {
        
        ParentId = p.Parent.Id,
        ParentName = p.Parent.Name,
        ParentOccupation = p.Parent.Occupation,
        NumberOfGrandChildren = p.GrandChildren.Count(),
        GranchildrenNames = string.Join(", ", p.GrandChildren.Select(gc => gc.Name))
    });
```

And here is a full working LinqPad script, with random data generation, so you can try it:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    var Parents = Enumerable
        .Range(0, 10)
        .Select(i => new Parent
        {
            Id = i,
            Name = $"Parent-{i}",
            Occupation = $"Occupation{i}"
        })
        .ToList();
    var Children = Enumerable
        .Range(0,15)
        .Select(i => new Child
        {
            Id = i,
            Name = $"Child{i}",
            ParentId = rnd.Next(0, 10)
        })
        .ToList();
    var GrandChildren = Enumerable
        .Range(0, 25)
        .Select(i => new GrandChildren
        {
            Id = i,
            Name = $"GrandChild{i}",
            ChildId = rnd.Next(0, 15)
        })
        .ToList();


    var Result = Parents
        // Stage 1: for each parent, get its Chidren Ids
        .Select(p => new
        {
            Parent = p,
            ChildrenIds = Children
                .Where(c => c.ParentId == p.Id)
                .Select(c => c.Id)
                .ToList()
        })
        // Stage 2: for each parent, get its Grandchildren, by using the childrenIds list constructed before
        .Select(p => new
        {
            p.Parent,
            GrandChildren = GrandChildren
                .Where(gc => p.ChildrenIds.Contains(gc.ChildId))
                .ToList()
        })
        // Stage 3: for each parent, count the grandchildren, and get their names
        .Select(p => new
        {
            
            ParentId = p.Parent.Id,
            ParentName = p.Parent.Name,
            ParentOccupation = p.Parent.Occupation,
            NumberOfGrandChildren = p.GrandChildren.Count(),
            GranchildrenNames = string.Join(", ", p.GrandChildren.Select(gc => gc.Name))
        })
        .Dump();
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChildren
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

And here is a set of results:

```
// Parents
0   Parent-0    Occupation0
1   Parent-1    Occupation1
2   Parent-2    Occupation2
3   Parent-3    Occupation3
4   Parent-4    Occupation4
5   Parent-5    Occupation5
6   Parent-6    Occupation6
7   Parent-7    Occupation7
8   Parent-8    Occupation8
9   Parent-9    Occupation9
```

```
// Children
0   Child0  1
1   Child1  5
2   Child2  8
3   Child3  6
4   Child4  9
5   Child5  3
6   Child6  0
7   Child7  4
8   Child8  9
9   Child9  7
10  Child10 8
11  Child11 2
12  Child12 7
13  Child13 7
14  Child14 8
```

```
// GrandChildren
0   GrandChild0 7
1   GrandChild1 11
2   GrandChild2 11
3   GrandChild3 14
4   GrandChild4 6
5   GrandChild5 0
6   GrandChild6 11
7   GrandChild7 6
8   GrandChild8 0
9   GrandChild9 12
10  GrandChild10    9
11  GrandChild11    7
12  GrandChild12    0
13  GrandChild13    3
14  GrandChild14    11
15  GrandChild15    9
16  GrandChild16    2
17  GrandChild17    12
18  GrandChild18    12
19  GrandChild19    12
20  GrandChild20    14
21  GrandChild21    12
22  GrandChild22    11
23  GrandChild23    14
24  GrandChild24    12
```

```
// Result
0   Parent-0    Occupation0 2   GrandChild4, GrandChild7
1   Parent-1    Occupation1 3   GrandChild5, GrandChild8, GrandChild12
2   Parent-2    Occupation2 5   GrandChild1, GrandChild2, GrandChild6, GrandChild14, GrandChild22
3   Parent-3    Occupation3 0   
4   Parent-4    Occupation4 2   GrandChild0, GrandChild11
5   Parent-5    Occupation5 0   
6   Parent-6    Occupation6 1   GrandChild13
7   Parent-7    Occupation7 8   GrandChild9, GrandChild10, GrandChild15, GrandChild17, GrandChild18, GrandChild19, GrandChild21, GrandChild24
8   Parent-8    Occupation8 4   GrandChild3, GrandChild16, GrandChild20, GrandChild23
9   Parent-9    Occupation9 0
```

Comment: I am getting this: "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Grandchild> .Where(s => DbSet<Child> .Where(s0 => s0.ParentId == (Nullable<int>)(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: Parent ValueBufferExpression: (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember) IsNullable: False ).Id) .Select(s0 => s0.Id) .ToList() .Contains(s.ChildId ?? 0))' could not be translated. 
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().".Will play around more and share if what works.

Comment: The error is caused by "Contains" that is not supported anymore by .Net Core 3.1.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412799/ef-core-3-1-throws-an-exception-for-contains) The solution I did to fix was to add ".ToList()" after "var Result = Parents".  Thank you, Laurent! The LINQPad script helped a lot too.

Comment: I edited my answer in light of your comments. Robert McKee's answer is more to the point since you are dealing apparently with interpreted queries rather than local queries. See my edited answer for more details. Ideally, you should specify if you are using Linq to Objects or Linq to Entities. You can also use Linqpad to perform interpreted queries (it is a great tool to experiment with. It also allows to inspect the generated SQL). If the distinction between Linq to Objects and Linq to Entities is not clear for you, you should look into it.

Comment: I will definitely read the link you shared, and take note of the difference so I can specify it better if I have a similar question in the future. Thanks for your help!