# C# Linq Expression could not be Translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to execute a linq query to get all employes that have some specific skills. search.skills is a list of strings with some skills and I want to retrieve all the user which have all those skills (And condition).
In my where clause on employees, exp.Skills is ICollection and expSkill.SkillName is the skill name

```
                .Where(
                emp => search.Skills.All(
                    searchSkill => emp.Experiences.Select(exp => exp.Skills).SelectMany(x => x).Select(expSkill => expSkill.SkillName).Contains(searchSkill)
                ))
            .ToListAsync();
```

I am getting the following error while trying to execute it. I am using entityframework core 3

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Employee>
.Where(e => __search_Skills_0
    .All(searchSkill => DbSet<Experience>
        .Where(e0 => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(e, "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(e, "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(e0, "EmployeeId"))
        .SelectMany(
            source: e0 => DbSet<ExperienceSkill>
                .Where(e1 => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(e0, "EmployeeId") != null && new AnonymousObject(new object[]
                { 
                    (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(e0, "EmployeeId"), 
                    (object)EF.Property<string>(e0, "ProjectCode") 
                }) == new AnonymousObject(new object[]
                { 
                    (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(e1, "ExperienceEmployeeId"), 
                    (object)EF.Property<string>(e1, "ExperienceProjectCode") 
                })), 
            collectionSelector: (e0, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<Experience, ExperienceSkill>(
                Outer = e0, 
                Inner = c
            ))
        .Select(ti => ti.Inner.SkillName)
        .Contains(searchSkill)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in my query? Thanks

Comment: The error says : "_Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()_". IEnumerable vs IQueryable, can be hard in EF to twist your mind around. I will try to find a reference question on SO that give a clear explanation on that

Comment: I see that your ".ToListAsync();" is not included in the error message and judging from indents it applies to an outer part of the query.  Maybe try applying one directly on the where clause?

Comment: I am applying .ToListAsync(); immediately after the where clause

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690473/entity-framework-3-0-contains-cannot-be-translated-in-sql-as-it-was-in-ef-core-2, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690473/entity-framework-3-0-contains-cannot-be-translated-in-sql-as-it-was-in-ef-core-2https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17342. May we have a look into class decalration?

Comment: Are the ID being store in database as GUID, int, or string?

Comment: ID are being stored as GUID in DB

Comment: I am using EF Core 3.1.1 version

Comment: Can you provide some schema information and DTO type information, its hard to see where the data is coming from in your expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF Core currently cannot translate LINQ operators other than simple `Contains` on memory collections like your `search.Skills`.

So you need to find an alternative to `memoryCollection.All` operator. What I use in such case is the "count matches" approach, which find all matching records and compares the counts of the distinct values.

e.g. replace

```
emp => search.Skills.All(
    searchSkill => emp.Experiences.Select(exp => exp.Skills).SelectMany(x => x).Select(expSkill => expSkill.SkillName).Contains(searchSkill)
```

with

```
emp => emp.Experiences
    .SelectMany(exp => exp.Skills, (exp, skill) => skill.SkillName)
    .Where(skillName => search.Skills.Contains(skillName))
    .Distinct().Count() == search.Skills.Distinct().Count()
```