# IQueryable with Where containing a list throws "No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'List<string>'."

Tags: asp.net-core, db2, entity-framework-core

While using IBM.EntityFrameworkCore and IBM.Data.DB2.Core an error is being thrown everytime when I have a `Where` statement containing a list on which some kind of verification is being performed.

The error is being thrown when the IQueryable is being materialized i.e. converted to a list using `ToList()`.

> No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type
>   'List'.

```
private IQueryable<CollectionActivityInOverview> FilterActivitiesForAdvisor(IQueryable<CollectionActivityInOverview> activitiesList, List<string> advisorCodes)
{
    List<AdvisorCustomerInfo>advisorInformation = GetAdvisorCustomers(advisorCodes).Result;
    var advisorCustomers = advisorInformation.SelectMany(a => a.Customers)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();

    // This is the problematic spot
    activitiesList = activitiesList.Where(a => advisorCustomers.Any(ac => ac == a.CustomerId));

    return activitiesList;
}
```

.

```
public class AdvisorCustomerInfo
{
    public string AdvisorCode { get; set; }

    public List<string> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

What could the error be, since AFAIK, conditions using lists should not only be supported by Linq to Entities, but also supported by Linq to SQL.

**Is it possible that DB2 Entity Framework library doesn't support i.e. doesn't translate such conditions into SQL?**

Can someone confirm it?

My main requirement is to keep IQueryable in order to execute the query against the database. Is it possible to rewrite the query using something else?

Comment: What does `GetAdvisorCustomers` do? Also, you're calling `.Result` here which is super dangerous. You should be `await`ing that call.

Comment: @DavidG Regarding `GetAdvisorCustomers`, it just delivers a list. Regarding await, this is the code I inherited so it's on a to-do list :)

Comment: I didn't understand the bit where your words say (paraphrase) "it's happening when I call ToList()" and your code comemnt says "it's happening on the line after I call ToList()"

Comment: @CaiusJard The error is being thrown whenever I perform .ToList(). Howewer, if I rewrite the `Where` using something simpler (basic string comparison for example) no error is thrown.

Comment: You cannot have a `List<string>` as a type in an entity, I assume that is why this is throwing your error.

Comment: @DavidG - It's not that, my main entity is activitiesList which is a simple object. The problem is IMO, somewhere with EF.

Comment: You could try the simpler condition `activitiesList.Where(a => advisorCustomers.Contains(a.CustomerId));`. `Contains` compares a value, where `Any` takes a predicate. No need for a predicate here.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Unfortunately, I already tried that but I get the same error.

Comment: Is `CollectionActivityInOverview` mapped? I.e., is there a DataSet in the context for it?

Comment: How about `advisorCustomers.Contains(a.CustomerId)` instead?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes, everything works as supposed. I think I know what the problem is. My company uses some kind of a wrapper for EF; it must be the cause of the problem since everything else seems to be ok.

Comment: It's not Db2 provider related, but EF Core and memory collections in general. The solution is to create memory collection with ids only and use `Contains` criteria. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60504903/c-sharp-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated/60507549#60507549

Comment: @Ivan Stoev - I also tried using Contains but it delivers the same error. The reason why am I insisting on IQueryable is because I have other methods that perform filtering as well.

Comment: `activitiesList` is and will remain `IQueryable`, we are talking about  `advisorCustomers`. Which now I see is `List<string>`, so `Contains` for sure works for all db providers I've seen (Db2 is not one of them) and is translated to SQL `IN (val1, val2, ...,, valN)`.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev - Thank you, this seems to be the confirmation of my assumption. Well, sometimes you can't have it all. However, I'll add the answer as soon as I solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that DB2 EF Core Library (at the moment) doesn't support using of `.Any()` or `.Contains()`. It is, however, possible to "override" this behaviour by writing a custom Expression that mimics SQL `WHERE` function with multiple conditions in the query.

Basically you pass the list you want to iterate and you append each item of the list to the Expression body using `Expression.OrElse()`. At the end you return the expression using `Expression.Call()`.