# Entity Framework 5.0 Contains/Equals/StartsWith/EndWith in Any cannot be translated in SQL as it was in EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to migrate a Linq query from EF Core 2.2 to EF Core 5.0 it was works perfect in 2.2

```
var foo = await _baseRepository.GetQueryable<User>().Where(i => new[] { "os", "man" }.Any(j => i.Email.Contains(j))).ToListAsync();
```

Error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>()
    .Where(u => string[] { "os", "man", }
        .Any(j => u.Email.Contains(j)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Also  I tried  `new[] { "os", "man" }.ToList()/AsEnumerable()`

Also this works

```
var foo = await _baseRepository.GetQueryable<User>().Where(i => new[] { "os" }.Any(j => i.Email.Equals(j))).ToListAsync();
```

Result Query

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = "os"
```

but this **not equals (... !Equals(..))** does not work

```
var foo = await _baseRepository.GetQueryable<User>().Where(i => new[] { "os" }.Any(j => !i.Email.Equals(j))).ToListAsync();
```

also i tried StartsWith/EndsWith but i got error

Related Quenstion : [Entity Framework 3.0 Contains cannot be translated in SQL as it was in EF Core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690473/entity-framework-3-0-contains-cannot-be-translated-in-sql-as-it-was-in-ef-core-2/58690829#58690829)

Comment: The "related question" is different though. `Enumerable.Contains` is supported in all EF Core versions. And is the only supported operation on in-memory collection. Also `Any` with `Equals` / `==`, because it equivalent of `Contans`. Any other operator inside `Any` will fail as you already found (partially).

Comment: You are right . Its my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was awhile ago (2 years); but a lot of LINQ statements break from 2.2 to 3.0. Your link lists both the reason (Core 3 throws an exception if it cannot convert LINQ to SQL statement and needs to pull records to memory without explicit `ToEnumerable()`) and suggested solutions.

So, it is not clear what you are asking. Unfortunately, these errors only come at runtime; so you need to go through all of them and - preferably - to use LINQ options that map to SQL; or - if it is not possible - to explicitly call `ToEnumerable()`

And if you need to fix them *before* upgrading, you can put a call in `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder
   .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Log(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, this worked in EF Core 2.2 because they allowed client-side evaluation which effectively did a big 'ol "SELECT *" or at least applied what filtering they could, then did the unsupported evaluations in memory.

In your example in EF Core 2.2:

```
var foo = await _baseRepository.GetQueryable<User>()
    .Where(i => new[] { "os", "man" }
        .Any(j => i.Email.Contains(j)))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Would be this in EF Core 5:

```
var foo = await _baseRepository.GetQueryable<User>()
    .ToListAsync() // <- materialize for client-side evaluation.
    .Where(i => new[] { "os", "man" }
        .Any(j => i.Email.Contains(j)))
    .ToListAsync();
```

**Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure that even works. You may need to await the `ToListAsync()` on the Get all, and then do the filtering as a separate operation..

```
var users = await _baseRepository.GetQueryable<User>()
    .ToListAsync(); // <- materialize for client-side evaluation.
var foo = await users.Where(i => new[] { "os", "man" }
        .Any(j => i.Email.Contains(j)))
    .ToListAsync();
```

While EF can understand `string.Contains()`, it cannot parse that with a `.Any()` against an in-memory set. Though this is certainly not ideal as you are loading *all* users before filtering.

To fix it so EF can translate it would be this:

```
var foo = await _baseRepository.GetQueryable<User>()
    .Where(i=> i.Email.Contains("os") 
        || i.Email.Contains("man")
    .ToListAsync();
```

However, where you want to be more dynamic like having that in-memory list composed of a variable/configurable set, then you need to look at Dynamic Linq. (https://dynamic-linq.net/) Specifically it's Nuget package to help you build an expression that EF can execute. This will allow you to compose an OR expression dynamically from a set of values to execute as part of your `Where` clause.